# How to save edited post when submitting form

Tags: admin

I have added a custom button(via form in html) on my WooCommerce edit product(same as WordPress edit past I think) page. When this button is pressed, my php code will parse the post content. The problem is that if I edit the post content, and do not first click the standard "Update" button, my edited content is lost. How can I add the standard WordPress "Update" button functionality to my custom form button?

This is my form I added, using the "add_meta_box" action:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<div>
<input type="submit" name="mxUpldImg" class="button-primary" alue="Upload Mx Img" />
</div>
</form>
```

I then check for my post using the "admin_init" action.

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing in the parsing function of the post content? You can do the same thing on the trigger of the standard update button to avoid data loss.

Please use the `save_post` hook to perform your function on the click of the standard update button. Please see the below link for documentation of save_post hook.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick reply! I am parsing it for a tag that contains the WooCommerce product image. If present, this image is used as my main product image and for eBay/Amazon listings. Just saves me some clicks when adding products. I do not want to parse for it every time the post is saved if possible. Do you know if I can maybe add a checkbox to my "edit post" page in stead of a button? I can then check $_post for my checkbox during post save? This would be a better solution than my current one.

Comment: UPDATE. I simply added input tags to my meta box, and see that they are available in $_POST. All sorted, thanks for the help!